# Как сделать resampling еженедельный по конкретному столбцу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country TotalCost
InvoiceDate                             
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER  6   2.55    17850.0 United Kingdom  15.30
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  71053   WHITE METAL LANTERN 6   3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  84406B  CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER  8   2.75    17850.0 United Kingdom  22.00
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE 6   3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  84029E  RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.  6   3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  22752   SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES    2   7.65    17850.0 United Kingdom  15.30
2010-12-01 08:26:00 536365  21730   GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER   6   4.25    17850.0 United Kingdom  25.50
2010-12-01 08:28:00 536366  22633   HAND WARMER UNION JACK  6   1.85    17850.0 United Kingdom  11.10
2010-12-01 08:28:00 536366  22632   HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT   6   1.85    17850.0 United Kingdom  11.10
2010-12-01 08:34:00 536367
```

Как сделать resampling данных в еженедельные со значениями суммы по столбцам TotalCost?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я делаю так

```
data.resample('W-MON')
```

Высвечивается:

```
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Week: weekday=0>, axis=0, closed=right, label=right, convention=start, base=0]
```

Почему в задании специально указан столбец TotalCost? Разве resampling не по всем данным делается равномерно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После ресемплинга обычно применяется агрегирующая функция:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=["InvoiceDate"], 
                          index_col="InvoiceDate", encoding="latin-1")

In [12]: df.resample('W-MON')[["Quantity", "UnitPrice"]].sum()
Out[12]:
             Quantity  UnitPrice
InvoiceDate
2010-12-06     100481   56405.97
2010-12-13     114652  138972.34
2010-12-20     102788   46884.58
2010-12-27      24307   18257.96
2011-01-03          0       0.00
2011-01-10      82505   68741.30
2011-01-17      89957   36682.09
...               ...        ...
2011-10-31     126685   76136.53
2011-11-07     163554   63246.22
2011-11-14     195267   77461.60
2011-11-21     157261   73853.57
2011-11-28     167211   78033.77
2011-12-05     167279  118021.94
2011-12-12     116047   50448.41

[54 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

Как бороться с NaN:

```
In [17]: df.resample('W-MON')[["Quantity", "UnitPrice"]].mean().head()
Out[17]:
             Quantity  UnitPrice
InvoiceDate
2010-12-06   7.165954   4.022677
2010-12-13   7.647035   9.269148
2010-12-20   9.673254   4.412251
2010-12-27   8.558803   6.428859
2011-01-03        NaN        NaN

In [18]: df.resample('W-MON')[["Quantity", "UnitPrice"]].mean().fillna(0).head()
Out[18]:
             Quantity  UnitPrice
InvoiceDate
2010-12-06   7.165954   4.022677
2010-12-13   7.647035   9.269148
2010-12-20   9.673254   4.412251
2010-12-27   8.558803   6.428859
2011-01-03   0.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: `Quantity UnitPrice CustomerID TotalCost
InvoiceDate    
2010-12-06 7.165954 4.022677 15636.376412 16.809830
2010-12-13 7.647035 9.269148 15560.060500 16.794917
2010-12-20 9.673254 4.412251 15333.703230 18.484338
2010-12-27 8.558803 6.428859 15273.918347 22.897472
**2011-01-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN**`

Comment: Появилась пустая строка . Пытаюсь от нее избавиться  `data.resample('W-MON').nearest().head()` Не исчезает

Comment: fillna() как то может применить

Comment: @svil, можете выложить ваш датасет?

Comment: `data.fillna(method='bfill')`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13qNaA3BV3aVhwYf89xok8ejucO8zNKAD